# The application just "stop unexpectedly" when run on the phone

Tags: android

When I run my application on the emulator, it run right and no problem happens. But when I run it on the phone, a problem appear "stop unexpectedly".

In my application: 
The main activity (Background) can exchange to 4 activities: LivingRoom, DiningRoom, Wc, Garage. The problem "stop unexpectedly" just happens when i try to go to the DiningRoom activity.

This is my code :

1.Background

```
package com.example.background;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino;


public class BackgroundActivity extends Activity {

    private Button Wc, Dining_Room, Living_Room, Garage;
    private Intent D_intent, L_intent, G_intent, W_intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        Living_Room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.living);
        //Living_Room.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Living_Room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                L_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LivingRoom.class);
                startActivityForResult(L_intent, 0);
            }

        });

        Dining_Room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dining);
       // Dining_Room.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Dining_Room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                D_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DiningRoom.class);
                startActivityForResult(D_intent, 0);
            }

        });

        Wc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wc);
        //Wc.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Wc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                W_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Wc.class);
                startActivityForResult(W_intent, 0);
            }

        });

        Garage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.garage);
       // Garage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Garage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                G_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Garage.class);
                startActivityForResult(G_intent, 0);
            }

        });


    }


}
```

2.DiningRoom

```
 package com.example.background;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    import at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino;


    public class DiningRoom extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener{


        private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:06:66:43:9B:56";


        final int DELAY = 150;

        ToggleButton button;
        SeekBar seekbar1;
        SeekBar seekbar2;

        boolean light2;

        int light1;
        int fan;
        long lastchange;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.diningroom);


                //back ve trang chinh 
                Button backhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.D_backhome);
                backhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                });


                Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);

                button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.Dbutton);
                seekbar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Dseekbar1);
                seekbar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Dseekbar2);

                button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
                seekbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

         }



        //---START----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         @Override
        protected void onStart(){

            super.onStart();

            // load last state
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            light2 = pref.getBoolean("light2", true);
            light1 = pref.getInt("light1", 0);
            fan = pref.getInt("fan", 0);

            button.setChecked(light2);
            seekbar1.setProgress(light1);
            seekbar2.setProgress(fan);

            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                    update_light2();
                    update_light1_fan();
                }
            }.start();
        }


         //STOP--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        protected void onStop(){

            super.onStop();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
                .putBoolean("light2", light2)
                .putInt("light1", light1)
                .putInt("fan", fan)
            .commit();

            Amarino.disconnect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        }

        //UPDATE LIGHT2--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void Update_Light2_State(final CompoundButton button){

                    light2 = button.isChecked();
                    update_light2();
        }


        private void update_light2(){

            int a;

            a = (light2 == true)? 255:0;
            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'o', a);
        }

        //UPDATE LIGHT1 FAN-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void Update_Light1_Fan_State(final SeekBar seekbar){

            switch (seekbar.getId()){
            case R.id.Dseekbar1:
                light1 = seekbar.getProgress();
                update_light1();
                break;
            case R.id.Dseekbar2:
                fan = seekbar.getProgress();
                update_fan();
                break;
            }

        }


        private void update_light1_fan(){

            update_light1();
            update_fan();
        }


        private void update_light1(){

            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'p', light1);
        }
        private void update_fan(){

            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'q', fan);
        }




        //---TRACE--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastchange > DELAY ){
                Update_Light2_State(button);
                lastchange = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastchange > DELAY ){
                Update_Light1_Fan_State(seekbar);
                lastchange = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {

            lastchange = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {

            Update_Light1_Fan_State(seekbar);
        }
    }
```

3.Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.background/com.example.background.DiningRoom}: java.lang.ClassCastException: 

java.lang.Boolean
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean
at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2721)
at com.example.background.DiningRoom.onStart(DiningRoom.java:80)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
... 11 more
Force finishing activity com.example.background/.DiningRoom
Force finishing activity com.example.background/.BackgroundActivity
```

I also try to wrote another application similar to the above application. But I just have only 1 sub activity: DiningRoom, then it ran well on the phone.

The Background when I just have one sub activity

[CODE]

```
public class Test1Activity extends Activity {

    private Button Dining_Room;
    private Intent D_intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Dining_Room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dining);
       // Dining_Room.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Dining_Room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                D_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Dining.class);
                startActivityForResult(D_intent, 0);
            }

        });

    }


}
```

[/CODE]

Answer (score 0):

Careful reading of logcat reveals that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean
```

at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2721)
at com.example.background.DiningRoom.onStart(DiningRoom.java:80)

This means,  that shared preference was boolean instead of int on line 80.

PS: I develop lightweight dependency injection framework for android,  and it already covers 
loading / saving preferences.  Just grab it here:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject

Comment: "light1" was int. the problem was that with the same code "DiningRoom", but the application run right when it just have one sub activity and have error when the application have four sub activities

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the value "light1" in your shared preferences was not saved as an integer (but as a boolean).
From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that
> is not an int.

Comment: "light1" was int. the problem was that with the same code "DiningRoom", but the application run right when it just have one sub activity and have error when the application have four sub activities

Comment: It also run on the emulator and just "stop unexpected" when i run on the phone

Comment: Maybe somewhere in one of the activities, you accidentally save a boolean to "light1" (instead of light2 maybe?)

Comment: "light1" just be used in the "DiningRoom". And with 4 sub activities, the application still run well on the emulator and just "stop unexpectedly" on the phone